# How can I optimize this code using valarray SIMD support?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, optimization, simd

Or using SIMD instructions?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#define  sz 10000;

typedef struct pixel{
    int b,g,r;
};

int main()
{
  pixel * src = new pixel[sz];  // arrays filled
  pixel * ker = new pixel[sz];  // by random values

  pixel px;
  px.r=px.g=px.b=0;
  for (int i=0; i<sz; i++){
      px.r+=src[i].r*ker[i].r;
      px.g+=src[i].r*ker[i].g;
      px.b+=src[i].r*ker[i].b;
  }


  return 0;
}
```

src - an array, contained of some random values.

ker - like src, contained of random values too.

the for cycle should be optimized

Comment: Shouldn't it be
`px.r+=src[i].r*ker[i].r;`
`px.g+=src[i].g*ker[i].g;`
`px.b+=src[i].b*ker[i].b;`
?

Comment: "blablabla just a text" - if you don't like the rules of this site, you're not forced to participate. If you want to participate, please adhere to them, they're here for a good reason.

Comment: @BartoszKP, sorry but i had no idea what i should write there

Comment: @justanothercoder, yeap, you're right

Comment: @DmitryKharatyan I understand :) However, you should post code optimization questions on [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/), not here. Instead of "blabla" write an explanation of what are you doing, and what have you achieved so far in your optimization attempts :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
#include <valarray>

#define sz 1000

struct pixel { int r, g, b; };

int main()
{
    std::valarray<int> src(3 * sz);
    std::valarray<int> ker(3 * sz);

    std::valarray<int> t = src * ker;

    pixel px;
    px.r = t[t % 3 == 0].sum();
    px.g = t[t % 3 == 1].sum();
    px.b = t[t % 3 == 2].sum();

    return 0;
}
```

I assume here that you have color values in `src` and `ker` in order `rgb rgb rgb rgb`.

Link to documentation http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray

Comment: thnx, but order is bgr bgr bgr , as color channel order in windows bmp standart

Comment: one more question - if r,g and b in the pixel struct will have the char type, will your solution work?

Comment: You can rewrite it that way that order would be `bgr`. It will work if `r, g, b` would be the `char` type.